# FQL query fails depending on user

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, photo

I wrote a query, trying to all the comments, given on my albums. The query I use is the following :

```
SELECT fromid, user_likes, text, time FROM comment 
WHERE object_id IN 
( 
    SELECT object_id FROM photo
    WHERE aid IN ( 
        SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=me() 
    )
)
```

In my case, when I test it on the developers site, it just returns:

```
{
   "data":  [
   ]
}
```

So I figured my query wasn't wrong because it returns no error so I asked a friend to try it and he did get all his comments on albums. The test page I used it the following :

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20fromid%2C%20user_likes%2C%20text%2C%20time%20FROM%20comment%20%0AWHERE%20object_id%20IN%20%0A(%20%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20object_id%20FROM%20photo%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20aid%20IN%20(%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SELECT%20aid%20FROM%20album%20WHERE%20owner%3Dme()%20%0A%20%20%20%20)%0A)%0A

And yes, I do have a valid access token because the following query does work:

```
SELECT object_id FROM photo
    WHERE aid IN ( 
        SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=me() 
    )
```

Is it possible it doesn't work because I'm a new user on facebook? Or can it be that it's a privacy setting? I compared all my privacy setting (album and profile) with my friend and we have exactly the same so I don't think so.

Also when I share an album with a link (go to album, click on wheel, share, copy link), people have to log in on facebook before they can see the album and if my friend does the same, people can watch it without being logged in (like it is suppose to work). Maybe this has something to do with it?

I tried google, facebook help, calling facebook and even looking for answers on the developer pages and this forum but no luck. So you guys are basically my final hope...

Thanks a million
De Wesp!

Answer (score -1):

you may have got this error

```
{
"error": {
"message": "(#601) Parser error: unexpected end of query.", 
"type": "OAuthException", 
"code": 601
 }
}
```

this is because when you creating an app you should create a token access for your apps.

Please let me know if it does not work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I don't think that's the case. It really return data, but just empty one. Even if I fill in an aID to a public album (which everyone can see and comment on), I still get empty data... And the ')' isn't part of the link, which it should be, so that's why you get the error :-) I just updated the link in my question

Comment: it seem like you access token does not have the permission user_photos .go to get access token on facebook and change the permission to include user_photos and generate the new token , now check it should return the user photos comment.

Comment: I'm 100% sure it has user_photo permission, when I click the get access token button, it is checked. In fact, just to be sure, I made a new one where ALL possible permissions are checked.

Comment: i am able to retrieve the comments , make sure you and your friends should have posted any thing , otherwise I am out of clues sorry :(

Comment: yeah there's tones of comments and likes on the photo's and albums. The weird thing is, my friend is also able to retrieve his comments (like you). But he has been on facebook since 2008 and me only for a few weeks. I have heard that new users get "less right's", don't know what to think of it or if it's even true. Thanks anyways, hopefully the problem just disappears after using facebook for a while :-)

Comment: maybe one more clue: all my aID's have underscores in them when I execute SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=me() , but my friend aID are shorter and don't have underscores in them when he executes the same query.

Comment: do one thing , run inner query first and see the result. SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=me()

Comment: Like I said, it works and returns all my album ID's but they are longer and contain an underscore, compared to the ones from my friend. For instance : 100004836091910_19270